# Return JSON elements separated by commas in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

In PHP, how can I return JSON elements values in a string separated by commas?

This is how I'm calling the "list" JSON file in PHP:

```
$list = file_get_contents('http://example.com/list/json');
$items = json_decode($list, true);
```

This is the List JSON content (may contain more items, and more columns for each, not only itemID):

```
{
 "resultCount":3,
 "results": [
{"itemId":1223604159},
{"itemId":1231618623},
{"itemId":1244303880}]
}
```

So I want this string as response:

```
1223604159,1231618623,1244303880
```

Already tried implode without success:

```
$IdByCommas = implode(',',$items->results->itemId);
```

Comment: Implode $items->results only

Comment: Sorry, my JSON file may contain other columns in each item, not only itemID. I put only itemID to make simpler to understand..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As every item of `$items->results` is an array with one key `itemId` you can't simply `implode($items['results'])`. You have to get every value of `itemId`.

With php5.5/5.6/7, where you have `array_column` function, you can:

```
echo implode(',', array_column($items['results'], 'itemId')));
```

Otherwise you have to extract every value of `itemId`:

```
$ids = [];
foreach ($items['results'] as $item) {
    $ids[] = $item['itemId'];
}
echo implode(',', $ids);
```

Also, I'm using `[]` instead of `->` because you decoded json to **array**, not object.

Comment: My JSON file may contain other columns in each item, not only itemID. I put only itemID to make simpler to understand.. I'm not getting it to work with your suggestion...